# react-native-admob Detect When Interstitial ad is Closed

Tags: react-native, admob, interstitial

In my current application i am using the react-native-admob package installed from npm in my application i can get my ads to show fine but i need to run a set function when the ad is closed by the user right now i am only using the Interstitial ad type

i have tried setting the event listner to run a function and placed the listener inside compenentwillmount using the code below

```
AdMobInterstitial.addEventListener('interstitialDidClose', () => {
  console.log('CLOSED');
  this.AdClosed('open');
});
```

but the AdClosed function is running as soon as the application is opened how do i run a function only when the user closes the Interstitial ad ?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I am creating and adding events to react-native Interstitial admob advertisement:

```
AdMobInterstitial.setAdUnitID("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917");
AdMobInterstitial.setTestDevices([AdMobInterstitial.simulatorId]);
AdMobInterstitial.requestAd().then(() => AdMobInterstitial.showAd());
AdMobInterstitial.addEventListener("adClosed", () => {
  //logic after ad have been closed
});

AdMobInterstitial.addEventListener("adFailedToLoad", () => {
  //logic if ad have failed to load
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
AdMobInterstitial.removeAllListeners(); //<- Add this line to close/remove event listener
AdMobInterstitial.setAdUnitID("ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX");
AdMobInterstitial.setTestDevices([AdMobInterstitial.simulatorId]);

AdMobInterstitial.requestAd().then(() => AdMobInterstitial.showAd());
AdMobInterstitial.addEventListener("adClosed", () => {
  //your stuff after ad is closed
});

AdMobInterstitial.addEventListener("adFailedToLoad", () => {
  //stuff if ad have failed to load
});
```

AdMobInterstitial.removeAllListeners(); does the work!!!